# CSS whole div hover

Tags: css

I am displaying multiple dibs with a class of box

Here is my CSS

```
.box {
  width:100%;
  min-height:20px;
  color:#000000;
  font-size:16px;
  border:1px solid #666666;
}
.box a {
   color:#000000;
   font-size:16px;
   text-decoration:underline;
}
.box a:hover {
   background:#666666;
}
```

How can I make the whole div have a background colour on hover?

Comment: `.box:hover` ... maybe?

Answer (score 0):

*I assume you don't want to change the background of the box if you hover over the box itself, but only if you hover over the anchor.*

It is possible if you change the divs like this.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <a href="#">Link</a>
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.container .box {
  width:100%;
  min-height:20px;
  color:#000000;
  font-size:16px;
  border:1px solid #666666;
}
.container a {
   color:#000000;
   font-size:16px;
   text-decoration:underline;
   float: left;
}
.container a:hover + .box {
   background:#666666;
}
```

Here is a **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6estt/)** example showing how it works

Comment: Can it be so if the whole box is hovered over?

Comment: Sure, change the :hover to the box... box:hover instead of .box a:hover. @charlie is that what you're asking???

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/AVasoVID/1/edit) how it works

CSS:

```
.box{
  background: gray;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 100px;
}

.box:hover{
  background: yellow;
}
```